# How to write Test Cases in Robot Framework with Selenium Library

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests, jython, robotframework

I have installed Robot Framework. I am searching for example Test Cases for Robot Framework using Selenium Library.

I need a guideline to start writing TCs on Robot Framework. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps this might help you figure it out [https://code.google.com/p/robotframework/wiki/JavaIntegration](https://code.google.com/p/robotframework/wiki/JavaIntegration)

Comment: @JakobBowyer: Thanks to provide the useful link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a Maven project of Robot Framework (RF) with Selenium2Library. The following are the steps to run:

Pre-requisite: Java (1.5 or newer), Maven

1. Download "robotframework-selenium2library-java-master.zip" from the following URL:

   https://github.com/MarkusBernhardt/robotframework-selenium2library-java
2. Unzip the folder
3. Open console/command prompt and go to the folder unzipped at step 2
4. Execute the maven command as: mvn clean install
5. Observe the execution: Google page will be opened in FF and do according to the Test Cases written
6. Observe the report on /target/robotframework-reports/report.html (the report is nice!!!)

[Note: It needs to analyse the folder and coding infrastructure. The codes are in src folder. It's important to understand the pom.xml]

The following link might be very helpful. There are step by step description how to write test cases in Getting Started section.

http://www.wallix.org/2011/07/26/how-to-use-robotframework-with-the-selenium-library/

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the above project is helpful as good example. But, there is no documentation for step by step explanation for writing TCs on Robot Framework with Selenium Library.

Comment: Yes, I have found the answer from the following that I asked:  http://www.wallix.org/2011/07/26/how-to-use-robotframework-with-the-selenium-library/

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your question what you're trying to achieve.
Do you want to run Robot Framework from Java ? Do you want to define keywords in Java?

I suspect you are aiming at the wrong tool.

First, Robot Framework tests are written in human-like language. Phrases are defined by **keywords** that can be implemented either as *user keywords* using the built-in language or as *external keywords* using Python/Java classes.

Second, Robot Framework is a tool to write **Acceptance Tests**. In such kind of tests, you pick your ***entire system*** and stimulate it with certain input and expect and verify a certain output/behaviour.

Now, what is important is **the system entry-point**. If your system entry-point is an executable it is not relevant if the testing process is in Python or Java; because all the test has to do is starting a new program.

If you interact with your system using a Java library then you need to define external keywords in Java using the library.

If you want to run Robot Framework from Java (without the need to install Python):

```
java -jar robotframework-2.6.3.jar --help
java -jar robotframework-2.6.3.jar mytests.txt
java -jar robotframework-2.6.3.jar --variable name:value mytests.txt
```

You find the jar here: https://code.google.com/p/robotframework/downloads/list

You will need to write some test cases before. I suggest to use RIDE ( https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE ) as test editor, but you need to install Python to run it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I might be unable to make you understand my question, sorry. My question is: "How to write test cases for Robot Framework?" NOT how to run RF.